# Python ThreadPoolExector memory leak?

Tags: python, multithreading, memory-management, python-multithreading

I'm busy trying to hunt down a issues I'm having in the google Pub/Sub library (https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/issues/273) and I think it's related to the memory being used by the ThreadPoolExector.

To test this, I created a very simple threaded daemon application to see what the memory looks like when running:

```py
from concurrent import futures
from random import seed
from random import randint
import time
import psutil
import os
import threading
import sys

PROCESS = psutil.Process(os.getpid())

def get_mem_usage():
    return PROCESS.memory_info().rss // 1024

def check_for_even(my_number: int) -> str:
  thread_name = threading.current_thread().getName()
  print(f"{thread_name} - Checking for even: {my_number}")
  if is_even(my_number):
    return my_number

  return None

def get_number() -> int:
  return randint(1, 10)

def is_even(random_number) -> int:
  if random_number % 2 == 0:
    return True

  return None

def got_number(future: futures.Future):

  thread_name = threading.current_thread().getName()

  x = [n for n in range(int(1e6))]
  result = future.result()

  if result:
    print(f"{thread_name} - Got even number: {result}")
  else:
    print(f"{thread_name} - Number was not even")

  thread_name = None
  del thread_name
  x = None
  del x
  result = None
  del result

def main():

  seed(int(time.time()))
  MAX_WORKERS = 5
  with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_WORKERS) as executor:
      
      future_list = []
      while (True):

        try:
          print(f"Memory: {get_mem_usage()}")
          number = get_number()
          future = executor.submit(check_for_even, number)
          future.add_done_callback(got_number)
          future_list.append(future)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
          executor._threads.clear()
          futures.thread._threads_queues.clear()
          raise

        print(f"Active thread count: {threading.active_count()}")
        if threading.active_count() - 1 >= MAX_WORKERS:
          for future in future_list:
            if future.done():
              future.cancel()
              future.result()
              future_list.remove(future)
          time.sleep(0.001)
          
        print(f"Future list count: {len(future_list)}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

When I run this memory just keeps increasing for the most part. Some memory is cleaned up on occasion (it seems like almost never), but the rate that it increases far outstrips the rate that it decreases by, which means that in a running application in production, the box will eventually run out of memory and the application will grind to a halt and crash.

Obviously, this is not ideal.

Am I doing something incorrect in the example above, or is there something I could be doing better to manage and free up memory for the application (using `gc.collect()` doesn't do much)?

Comment: This actually seems to happen more on my mac when running through pyenv, if I run through docker, it seems better.